# First observation that the Sun and Jupiter (and friends) move around a common barycenter?

Tags: the-sun, solar-system, history

Answers to the question [How did Kepler determine the orbital period of Mars?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/4834/7982) describing careful observations centuries ago got me thinking.

What was the first analysis of observations that directly demonstrated that the Sun and the outer giant planets were moving around a common barycenter rather than all planets rotating around a fixed Sun?

I am not sure if [First observation that the movement of a planet or asteroid in its orbit was affected by another planet?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/29741/7982) is a completely separate question, or if this confirmation happened all at once, but I've currently asked it separately.

Comment: I don't think so. Jupiter shouldn't be that massive to affect the Sun. It is only in rather large planet and small star systems where the affect can be noticed. I would rather think that the planets orbit the Sun in a point inside the star rather than an external barycenter.

Comment: Wait ah after some equations and using Wolfram Alpha I think you are right! Jupiter orbit at a barycenter! The barycenter for Jupiter is 1.07 solar radiuses from the center.

Comment: @Max0815 The Sun's orbit is a swirly pattern. There's a nice plot somewhere in Wikipedia and in several different answers here and other SE sites, but here's some plots I made: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/20019/7982

Comment: Then, I think your statement "the Sun **and the outer giant planets** were moving around a common barycenter rather than all planets rotating around a fixed Sun?" is incorrect. Only Jupiter is massive enough to have a barycenter. The next massive planet is Saturn, which is 1/3 the mass of Jupiter. This means the "barycenter" for it is .356 solar radii which isn't a barycenter at all.

Comment: oh, ok. its late. I'll read thru your plots and see if I can come up with an answer after some research tomorrow.

Comment: @Max0815 any statement about things moving in orbits is incorrect so some degree, this is understood in orbital mechanics. Even a [non-keplerian, non-newtonian n-body numerical simulation of the solar system](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/23409/12102) doesn't include gravitational effects from things *outside* the solar system. As soon as you say the word "orbit" you've started down the rabbit hole of approximations.

Comment: Hey @Max0815 Here's the swirly diagram of the solar system barycentre that uhoh mentioned. https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/28036/16685

Comment: @uhoh I'll need to look more into this. More complicated than I thought xD.

Comment: @uhoh I don't know anything about this topic, and I can't to seem to find a source on this topic other than articles saying the barycenter is 1.07 solar radii.

Comment: @Max0815 The 1.07 is only for the Sun-Jupiter system. The other large planets (Saturn, Uranus, Neptune) are not as heavy as Jupiter but they are farther out and the combined motion moves the Sun almost 2 solar radii at maximum.

Comment: Not the same question, and no mention of the first measurement, but related:   https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/258539/error-measurement-barycenter-of-the-solar-system-nasa-data   I would suggest, but I can't say for certain, that because Newton worked out the mathematics of the two body problem, and combined with difficulty in directly measuring this, that direct observation of a barycenter may not have been a priority. Probably the easiest place to observe it would be Jupiter and it's moons.  Jupiter tugs on the Earth as well as the sun, so that's more of a 3 body or tidal effect.

Comment: Wouldn't any "analysis of observations" of planetary motions involve use of Newton's theory of gravity (what else?). But Newton's theory implies the barycenter. The only way to have a "fixed Sun" is if its inertial mass is infinite (or very large compared to its gravitational mass). I doubt that anyone ever proposed a "fixed Sun" theory (although it would have been a test of the gravitational-inertial mass equivalence).

Comment: @KeithMcClary This is why I've asked for the first *observation*, and not "when was it realized that...". The data and analysis need to be careful enough to show that the Sun moves around a system barycenter. So the ratio of the Sun's mass to that of Jupiter will be in there somewhere, meaning that the first time that ratio was measured is likely to also be the answer to this question.

Comment: The barycentre cannot be directly observed (otherwise the hunt for Planet Nine would be a lot easier), so answering this really depends on your own opinion of what constitutes an observation of the barycentre, and the follow-up comments here show that opinions differ between the various contributors.

Comment: @antispinwards all one has to do is to show that the big planets are moving the Sun around measurably. Whenever that was first shown, that's the answer to my question.

Comment: @uhoh - showing it's moving relative to what? The Sun's motion relative to the zodiac was known by ancient civilisations and shows the Sun is moving, but provides no motivation for defining an Earth-Sun barycentre or choosing that rest frame to be fixed. Does this count as observing the Sun moving relative to the barycentre or not? I'd say that's a matter of opinion and quibbling over semantics.

Comment: @antispinwards In orbits, movement involves *acceleration* and once that happens we can no longer dismiss the topic as quibbling. To your question "...relative to what?" my answer is *any inertial frame*.

Comment: @uhoh - the Solar System barycentre is not an inertial frame though (accelerations due to nearby stars, the overall galaxy, etc.). You are quibbling over what constitutes an observation, when the point you're interested in fundamentally cannot be observed but is a conceptual point that enables mathematical convenience.

Comment: @antispinwards I didn't say the SS Bary. is an inertial frame. However the Sun's acceleration due to the big planets varies on an observational timescale; years and decades. *Variation in acceleration of the Sun due to the interstellar gravity field* would be much smaller on the same time scale. I really am not quibbling, one is much bigger than the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This idea would be a direct reduction from Newton's laws of motion.  In his [Principia](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Newton%27s_Principia_(1846).djvu/408) he states "Hence the common centre of gravity of the earth, the sun, and all the planets, is to be esteemed the centre of the world".  So that would be the first evidence of the Sun moving outside of a geocentric universe.  Of course he wouldn't have known about Uranus and Neptune at the time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as I also mentioned in [this comment](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/29742/first-observation-that-the-sun-and-jupiter-and-friends-move-around-a-common-ba/33227#comment61470_29742) I've asked for the *first observation* rather than the first realization.

Comment: You'll want to update the question then or post a new one, this one specifically asks for __analysis of observations__.

Comment: **...that directly demonstrated that the Sun and the outer giant planets were moving around a common barycenter.** I have a hunch that the answer to my question will coincide with the first measurement of the mass of the Sun or more likely, the ratio of the masses of Jupiter and the Sun. If you'd like to specifically cite his [analysis of solar parallax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_mass#History) then that could be an answer, though it seems he was so far off it was probably just wrong. But just saying "Newton said in a book that they go around a common center" isn't enough.

Comment: just fyi, while the bounty expires in about 15 hours, there's a further 24 hour "grace period".

Comment: "Analysis of observations" and "Observations" are different things.  Newtons entire Principia is about showing how his laws of motion fit to prior observations, just one conclusion of which is the solar system barrycenter.  It sounds like you're looking for something else, so good luck.